# Correct way to import lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash, babeljs

I had a pull request feedback below, just wondering which way is the correct way to import lodash?

> You'd better do import has from 'lodash/has'.. For the earlier version
>   of lodash (v3) which by itself is pretty heavy, we should only import
>   a specidic module/function rather than importing the whole lodash
>   library. Not sure about the newer version (v4).

```
import has from 'lodash/has';
```

vs

```
import { has } from 'lodash';
```

Thanks

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45305804/1541563) for a more in-depth discussion as to why the latter can still incur a performance optimization in some environments such as Webpack. It's due to the use of static-analysis and tree-shaking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Import a Single Lodash Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479464/how-to-import-a-single-lodash-function)

Answer (score 333, accepted):

`import has from 'lodash/has';` is better because lodash holds all its functions in a single file, so rather than import the whole 'lodash' library at 100k, it's better to just import lodash's `has` function which is maybe 2k.

Comment: Is this true for both v3 and v4?

Comment: @SungWonCho i think so, i am currently on 3.9.1, so i am sure v4 will do the same

Comment: I can confirm that your answer works for v4 as well.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos you just import the function you want to use, you don't need '_'

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to add to your answer that you need to install the separate npm method package in order to be able to import it.. For example `npm install lodash/has - - save`

Comment: what about the dot syntax: `import has from 'lodash.has'`?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos `'lodash/has'` isn't a separate package. There's a file called `has.js` in the root of the regular `'lodash'` package, and `import has from 'lodash/has'` (or `const has = require ('lodash/has`) will load that file. There *are* separate method packages on npm, but they use the "dot syntax": `'lodash.has'`. This would also be a valid way to go about it if you don't mind installing a separate package for *every* method you use (and potentially making your `package.json` massive as a result).

Comment: I have to add here that, if you use webpack 2 or rollup (a bundler that supports tree shaking), then `import { has } from 'lodash'` would work the same way, since the rest will be stripped out

Comment: Is it okay to import functions that are already defined in the global scope, for example, `import isFinite from 'lodash/isFinite';`, or `import find from 'lodash/find';`?

Comment: @nnyby that's fine, but why would you want to declare at global scope? if you want to do global scope, you will have to do `import find from 'lodash/find'; global.find = find;` i don't recommend that tho

Comment: @AlexJM you commented a while ago, but may I ask what plugin you would need to accomplish that with webpack 2? or does it do that automatically?

Comment: @PDN webpack 2 tree shaking should do it for you automatically

Comment: unlike some others, my tree shaking wouldn't work with the more obvious syntax, it was only after I switched to lodash-es and used the `import has from 'lodash-es/has'` syntax did I get full tree shaking.  went from 526KB to 184KB, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991178/correct-way-of-importing-and-using-lodash-in-angular

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos it's unnecessary to `import _ from 'lodash'` if you call range without preceding it by an underscore: `range(.,.)` as opposed to `_.range(.,.)`.

Comment: @AlexJM i just tried your suggestion with webpack 3+ and it doesn't work. Getting full library loaded.

Comment: @AlexJM is there anywhere else you are import the entire loadash?

Answer (score 156):

If you are using `webpack 4`, the following code is tree shakable.

```
import { has } from 'lodash-es';
```

The points to note;

1. CommonJS modules are not tree shakable so you should definitely use [`lodash-es`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es), which is the Lodash library exported as ES Modules, rather than [`lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) (CommonJS).
2. `lodash-es`'s package.json contains `"sideEffects": false`, which notifies webpack 4 that all the files inside the package are side effect free (see https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free).
3. This information is crucial for tree shaking since module bundlers do not tree shake files which possibly contain side effects even if their exported members are not used in anywhere.

**Edit**

[As of version 1.9.0, Parcel also supports `"sideEffects": false`](https://medium.com/@devongovett/parcel-v1-9-0-tree-shaking-2x-faster-watcher-and-more-87f2e1a70f79), threrefore `import { has } from 'lodash-es';` is also tree shakable with Parcel.
It also supports tree shaking CommonJS modules, though it is likely tree shaking of ES Modules is more efficient than CommonJS according to [my experiment](https://github.com/kimamula/tree-shaking-demo).

Comment: I converted all of my lodash imports to `import { ... } from 'lodash-es';`  My bundle still includes the whole library.

Comment: @IsaacPak Make sure that you are not transpiing ES modules to CommonJS. If you are using TypeScript, you have to set `--module` compiler option as `es6`, `es2015` or `esnext`.

Comment: I'm not using TypeScript and my .babelrc env preset is set to `modules: false` so they aren't transpiled to CommonJS.  I am using Bruce's solution now which seems to work.  Thanks for your contribution, I'm sure it works but I just don't have the setup for it.

Comment: unfortunately, can't use lodash-es with jest at this point:
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4842#issuecomment-491434065

Comment: @IsaacPak  read: [treeshaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#conclusion)

Comment: `import has from 'lodash-es/has'` and `import {has} from 'lodash-es'` both variants do treeshaking when using `webpack-4`

Comment: @Legends is correct. Lodash v4 with Webpack v4 does not require -es for it to be tree-shakeable. See: https://www.azavea.com/blog/2019/03/07/lessons-on-tree-shaking-lodash/

Comment: Didn't say that. `Lodash` uses `CommonJS` syntax, you cannot import from a CJS module. So you have to use `lodash-es` which uses `ES` module syntax and therefore enables treeshaking in webpack.

Comment: Does **not** work when using the `jest`: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5241

Answer (score 29):

> Import specific methods inside of curly brackets
>
> ```
> import { map, tail, times, uniq } from 'lodash';
> ```
>
> Pros:
>
> - Only one import line(for a decent amount of functions)
> - More readable usage: map() instead of _.map() later in the javascript code.
>
> Cons:
>
> - Every time we want to use a new function or stop using another  - it needs to be maintained and managed

Copied from:[The Correct Way to Import Lodash Libraries - A Benchmark](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark) article written by Alexander Chertkov.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. However, I like the `_.map()` syntax to be clear that an external library is being used. Is `import _ from 'lodash'` equally efficient as your suggestion or is there another way of being able to use this syntax?

Comment: @ToivoSäwén I completely agree and prefer the explicit `_.map()` syntax as well. Were you able to figure out a way to maintain that while doing es6 imports and tree-shaking?

Comment: This answer seems like a simple copy and paste from https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark. If so, it would be better to provide credit.

Comment: `import { map as _map, tail } from 'lodash'`

Comment: the article linked actually states the smallest bundle size, without some special plugins, is "one-by-one or ‘modules’ import". e.g.  `import map from "lodash/map"`

Answer (score 12):

You can import them as

```
import {concat, filter, orderBy} from 'lodash';
```

or as

```
import concat from 'lodash/concat';
import orderBy from 'lodash/orderBy';
import filter from 'lodash/filter';
```

the second one is much optimized than the first because it only loads the needed modules

then use like this

```
pendingArray: concat(
                    orderBy(
                        filter(payload, obj => obj.flag),
                        ['flag'],
                        ['desc'],
                    ),
                    filter(payload, obj => !obj.flag),
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using babel, you should check out [babel-plugin-lodash](https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash), it will cherry-pick the parts of lodash you are using for you, less hassle and a smaller bundle.

It has a few [limitations](https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash#limitations):

- You must use ES2015 imports to load Lodash
- Babel < 6 & Node.js < 4 aren’t supported
- Chain sequences aren’t supported. See this [blog post](https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba) for alternatives.
- Modularized [method packages](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized) aren’t supported

Answer (score 2):

I just put them in their own file and export it for node and webpack:

```js
// lodash-cherries.js
module.exports = {
  defaults: require('lodash/defaults'),
  isNil: require('lodash/isNil'),
  isObject: require('lodash/isObject'),
  isArray: require('lodash/isArray'),
  isFunction: require('lodash/isFunction'),
  isInteger: require('lodash/isInteger'),
  isBoolean: require('lodash/isBoolean'),
  keys: require('lodash/keys'),
  set: require('lodash/set'),
  get: require('lodash/get'),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66084580) can be used in any project easily and brings the best result with less effort.

For Typescript users, use as following :

```
// lodash.utils.ts
export { default as get } from 'lodash/get';
export { default as isEmpty } from 'lodash/isEmpty';
export { default as isNil } from 'lodash/isNil';
...
```

And can be used the same way as importing lodash :

```
//some-code.ts
import { get } from './path/to/lodash.utils'

export static function getSomething(thing: any): any {
    return get(thing, 'someSubField', 'someDefaultValue')
}
```

Or if you prefer to keep the `_` to avoid conflicts (ex. `map` from `rxjs` vs `lodash`)

```
//some-other-code.ts
import * as _ from './path/to/lodash.utils'

export static function getSomething(thing: any): any {
    return _.get(thing, 'someSubField', 'someDefaultValue')
}
```

UPDATE :
Seems like the right way to export is :

```
export * as get from 'lodash/get';
export * as isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';
export * as isNil from 'lodash/isNil';
...
```

But there is a weird collision with `@types/lodash`, I've removed this type package because I would get this error :

> Module '"/../project/node_modules/@types/lodash/cloneDeep"' uses
> 'export =' and cannot be used with 'export *'.ts(2498)

UPDATE :

After some digging, I've turned `tsconfig.json` feature [esModuleInterop](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) to `true`, and it allows me to do the following :

```
import get from 'lodash/get';
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';
import isNil from 'lodash/isNil';
...

export { get, isEmpty, isNil, ... };
```

Note that this affects all your imports in your projects that has been defined as `import * as lib from 'lib'`. Follow the documentation to be sure it's suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

`import { cloneDeep, groupBy } from 'lodash';`

I think this is simpler when you don't need to convert array to lodash object by using _.

`const groupData = groupBy(expandedData, (x) => x.room.name);`

Answer (score -2):

For those who want to keep using _ , then just import them like this:

```
import groupBy from 'lodash/groupBy';
import filter from 'lodash/filter';
import get from 'lodash/get';

window._ = {groupBy, filter, get};
```

Answer (score -7):

I think the more cleaner way  of importing lodash is just like this:-

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

then you can use what ever you want  just by using this underscore just like this:-

```
_.has()
```

Comment: if you do that, lodash will load the whole package. This is heavy for the app bundle. Cf. the documentation