# Delay suggestion time in Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Anyone knows how to delay time before it gives suggestions?

As soon as I write the first letter it gives me suggestions, I'd like to delay that, I read through the docs and couldn't find it, maybe it's not possible?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I need to do the same thing

Answer (score 14):

The conventional way is to use `debounce` or `throttle` to delay the function call while the user is typing. The delay behaviors are a bit different between them, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25991510/9449426) for more info. For this answer I'll use `debounce` from `lodash`.

Also please *do not* copy the most upvoted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40811671/9449426). It is wrong and uses bad practice:

- It imports the whole lodash package, which contains brazillions of [other methods](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) that you probably don't need and will increase your final [bundle size](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=lodash@4.17.21). The [correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251059/9449426) to do it is to use this import syntax instead:

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce
```

- It passes the result of `debounce(handleSearch)` directly to the `onUpdateInput` props. `debounce` is a higher-order function, it is a function factory that creates another function that can be delayed:

```js
const handleSearch = () => { // ... }
const handleSearchDelayed = debounce(handleSearch, 50);

handleSearchDelayed();
handleSearchDelayed();
handleSearchDelayed();

// handleSearchDelayed is called 3 times but handleSearch will only be called 1 time
// 50ms later
```

This means that the `debounce(handleSearch)` will create a new function with its own delay timer every time the component is re-render which is every time the user types in the textfield. This will create unexpected side-effects or even make the component not working at all.

The solution is to use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to return the same instance of the delay function when the component re-renders. Below is the minimal working example:

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Autocomplete from '@mui/lab/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import debounce from "lodash/debounce";
import { getOptionsAsync } from "./options";

function App() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
  const getOptionsDelayed = useCallback(
    debounce((text, callback) => {
      setOptions([]);
      getOptionsAsync(text).then(callback);
    }, 200),
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    getOptionsDelayed(inputValue, (filteredOptions) => {
      setOptions(filteredOptions);
    });
  }, [inputValue, getOptionsDelayed]);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      filterOptions={(x) => x} // disable filtering on client
      loading={options.length === 0}
      onInputChange={(e, newInputValue) => setInputValue(newInputValue)}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" />}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 40811535/delay-suggestion-time-material-ui-autocomplete-component]

Comment: Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 9):

You can use lodash's debounce() function (basically a little window.setTimeout trick to throttle repeated calls):

```
import _ from 'lodash';

...

doSearch(text) {
   // Your normal handler here
}

...

// Delay autocomplete until 500 ms after use stops typing
<AutoComplete
  onUpdateInput={_.debounce((value) => doSearch(value), 500)}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 7):

There is example from my project with AutoComplete from Antd package:

```
const { AutoComplete } = antd

const WAIT_INTERVAL = 1000
let timerID

class Test extends React.Component {

    handleSearch = (query) => {
        clearTimeout(timerID)

        timerID = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('some action after delay')
        }, WAIT_INTERVAL)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <AutoComplete
                ...
                onSearch={handleSearch}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I am assuming `1000` is in `millisecond`, ?

Comment: @sphoenix, yes it is

Comment: this is the best solution. Plain, simple javascript and no external packages!