# Angular CLI output - how to analyze bundle files

Tags: angular, angular-cli, tree-shaking

I am using Angular CLI to build an app for production using the `--prod` switch.
The bundle is created in the **dist** directory.
Is there a way to know which classes and functions have been actually put in the bundle after tree-shacking and all other steps?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

**UPDATE 2024 (v17 and above)**

In case you are using the latest [Angular](https://angular.dev) (Vite set by default from [Angular v17](https://blog.angular.io/introducing-angular-v17-4d7033312e4b)) then you have to try [esbuild analyze (official)](https://esbuild.github.io/analyze/) or [esbuild-visualizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-visualizer) to inspect your bundle size.
You need to enable the `statsJson` option in `angular.json`. Then you will have a `stats.json` in your `dist` folder.

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
    "options": {
      "statsJson": true,
      ...
    }
  }
```

---

**UPDATE 2020 (v16 and below)**:

The Angular team **strongly recommends** to only use **source-map-explorer** to analyze your bundle size instead of *webpack-bundle-analyzer*. According to them, webpack-bundle-analyzer and a few other similar tools doesn't give the actual info pertaining to Angular build process.

More info can be fount at *web.dev* - https://youtu.be/B-lipaiZII8?t=215

To install source-map-explorer globally:-

```
npm i -g source-map-explorer
```

or

```
yarn global add source-map-explorer
```

To analyze bundle size :-

```
source-map-explorer dist/my-awesome-project/main.js
```

> Remember to have source maps ready: they can be obtained by building
> with  `ng build --prod --source-map`. However since v12 you [don't really need to pass `--prod` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60471339/415078)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:
You can use [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to inspect your bundles.

- `npm install webpack-bundle-analyzer --save-dev`
- modify your `package.json` `scripts` section with `"analyze": "ng build --prod --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"`
- `npm run analyze`

You can checkout this [repo](https://github.com/kuncevic/angular-modular-project-structure) it is just a simple angular app that demonstrates how to implement lazy loading and it has [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) already setup as above.

Also you can configure Angular CLI [budgets](https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-size-budgets) to monitor your bundles size.

UPDATE:
Also with [@ngx-builders/analyze](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-builders/analyze) you can do:

- ng add @ngx-builders/analyze
- npm i source-map-explore -g
- ng run [YOUR_PROJECT_NAME]:analyze

**UPDATE:**
In case if you are using [nx console (aka angular console)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nrwl.angular-console) now it has [bundle analyzing feature](https://blog.nrwl.io/angular-console-7-4-release-2d4d3c654e8e) built-in also bear in mind that `stats.json`path might be different for each project stated by @Klaster_1 in comments.

Comment: Note: path to stats.json might be different for each project.

Comment: Also needs `--output-hashing=none` to have main.js without hash - please add to command above

Comment: `source-map-explorer dist/my-awesome-project/main*.js` accounts for output hashing; `source-map-explorer dist/my-awesome-project/*.js` is also worth considering to analyze lazy loaded modules at the same time.

Comment: It now seems to be `--source-map=true`, not `--sourceMap=true`.

Comment: it's almost 2024, this recommendation is still valid?

Comment: @ismaestro updated, thanks for point out

Comment: How can I generate the meta file with browser-esbuild for angular 17?
Without the file the analyzers won't work :/

Comment: same question although 2023 ;). How to let angular builder generate meta file

Comment: @cmxl & kerosene check the updated answer.

Answer (score 22):

#### 2020 angular team recommendation

The angular team **strongly recommends** to only use **source-map-explorer** to analyze your bundle size instead of *webpack-bundle-analyzer*. According to them, webpack-bundle-analyzer and a few other similar tools doesn't give the actual info pertaining to angular build process.

More info can be found at *web.dev* - https://youtu.be/B-lipaiZII8?t=215

To install source-map-explorer globally:-

```
npm i source-map-explorer
```

or

```
yarn global add source-map-explorer
```

To analyze bundle size :-

```
source-map-explorer dist/my-awesome-project/main.js
```

Remember to have your source map files available (which can be obtained by building with `ng build --prod --source-map=true`)

SIDE NOTE: I have personally used webpack-bundle-analyzer for quite a long time. But from now on source-map-explorer.

Comment: Please keep in mind that first you need to build your project with source maps enabled, like ` ng build --prod --sourceMap=true`

Answer (score 9):

### Edit [2020-06-08]

The Angular Console has been renamed to [Nx Console](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nrwl.angular-console). When you go to the console in VSCode you can run the **build** command with the **statsJson** option enabled. This generates, depending on your TypeScript configuration, some **stats-es*.json** files into the build directory alongside the compiled stuff. These you can use with the **webpack-bundle-analyzer** (as mentioned in the accepted answer)

```
npx webpack-bundle-analyzer ./pathto/stats-es2015.json
```

adjust the EcmaScript number according to your settings.

### Old Answer

Since [Angular console](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nrwl.angular-console) 7.4, there is a new way analyzing your Angular bundles.

- Install the vscode extension "Angular Console" by Nrwl technologies.
- Optional: If you haven't, turn your workspace into an nrwl-nx-workspace with `ng add @nrwl/schematics` (this is just an extended angular workspace, but it works with the default angular workspace, too).
- Go to **Projects** > Select the app you want to build and run the build command with *aot* and *production*.

And that's it. The output is the following. It contains the bundle size and all parts of the bundle. You can select the file you want to analyze (main/polyfills/1/etc). It will display that pie for each of that files. Pretty detailed and easy to use.

[image]

Comment: Is it still work? If so, can you elaborate on how you get this view?

Comment: The Angular Console has been renamed to Nx Console. I'll have a look if it is still similar.

Comment: There was no renaming. https://nx.dev/ is a completely different project ( built on top of the ng-cli, but completely different, amazing, project )

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to add webpack code analyzer to your angular app

```
    - cd into your angular app
    > npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-analyzer
    - Add below lines to script block of package.json
      "build:stats": "ng build --stats-json",
      "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/<your-project>/stats.json" ,
      "build-analyze": "npm run build:stats && npm run analyze",
    > npm run build-analyze
```

Comment: This didn't work, but I switched  `"analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"` with  ` "analyze": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/<my project name>/stats.json"` and it's finally working. Thanks for the help!