# Are --prod and --aot options required in Ivy in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular9, angular-builder

Starting from `angular 9`, angular started using a new renderer engine called `IVY` and as its document says the built code will look same in dev and prod environment and easy to debug, is it still required to pass `--prod` and `--aot` option while building code

old build command

`ng build --aot --prod`

is not it new command should look like

`ng build  //for both prod and dev build`

or only the `--prod` option is required for the prod build

Answer (score 4):

Aot was never required, it was default set to on in the production build, and off in development. Now aot is standard on for all environments, because of the speed improvements. So for a development build you do:

```
ng build
```

and for a production build

```
ng build --prod
```

You can check your angular.json file to see which setting does what. The `--prod` did more than just turning on the ahead of time compiler. A whole lot of other optimizations are being done during this build

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2022:
Since version v12 `ng build` now produces production bundle by default. However historically `--prod` was an alias for `--configuration=production`. More details at https://angular.io/guide/build

---

**TLTR;**
`--aot` flag does not requited when you use `--prod` e.g `ng build --prod`

---

JIT compilation is the default when you run the `ng build` (build only) or `ng serve` (build and serve locally) CLI commands. For AOT compilation, include the `--aot` option with the `ng build` or `ng serve` commands:

`ng build --aot`
`ng serve --aot`

> The `ng build` command with the `--prod` meta-flag (`ng build --prod`)
> [compiles with AOT by default](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#choosing-a-compiler)

You can customize your `angular.json` to include `aot` as default for a particular command, here is how you add aot for `build`:

```
"build": {
    options {
        ...
        "aot": true,
    } 
}
```

> AOT `build` and `serve` is recommended by angular team but not default
> yet. More details [here](https://angular.io/guide/ivy#aot-and-ivy)

Comment: so is anything changed after angular 9?

Comment: @AniruddhaDas really noting changed in regards to that, speaking `--aot` was default when building `--prod` for really long time since Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.28

Answer (score 1):

Default aot value depends on which angular version your are running:

Angular offers two ways to compile your application:

- Just-in-Time (JIT), which compiles your app in the browser at
  runtime. This was the default until **Angular 8**.
- Ahead-of-Time (AOT), which compiles your app and libraries at
  build time. This is the default since **Angular 9**.