Angular 17 Vite + ESBuild bundle size increase
I've updated an Angular 17 project to the new Vite + ESBuild build system, and noticed that the bundle size increased:
WebPack Build:

ESBuild + Vite Build:

The new Vite + ESBuild version built the project faster than Webpack, which isn't a surprise. But what I didn't expect was the initial bundle size to increase so much (2.01Mb to 2.24Mb).
I followed Angular's official docs to update the project.
Besides the build speed, aren't the bundle sizes suppose to decrease with ESBuild? Am I missing any extra configurations that would help reduce the initial bundle?
UPDATE:
Since I first posted this question I've added extra dependencies and upgraded the project to Angular 18.
Even though the overall bundle has increased, the estimated transfer size between the two build systems decreased a little. But there's still a noticeable difference between the two raw bundle sizes:
WebPack Build:

ESBuild + Vite Build:

My questions still remains: Besides the build speed, aren't the bundle sizes suppose to decrease with ESBuild? Or are we only going to see noticeable improvements with bigger dependencies?
Right now, I don't see any reason to upgrade my project to ESBuild + Vite. I'll try again in a couple of months when more dependencies are added.
UPDATE #2:
I've updated my Angular project to version 19, and noticed that the difference between the two build systems is insignificant now. Well, the bad news is that Angular's v19 increased the bundle size:

Angular v18.2.14 (WebPack): 1.90 MB // 332.06 kB
Angular v19.0.3 (WebPack): 1.94 MB // 341.45 kB
Angular v19.0.3 (ESBuild + Vite): 1.94 MB / 341.76 kB

Given the small differences, I decided to use the new ESBuild + Vite build system.
It's worth noting that the ESBuild+Vite has much faster build times, but will preform worst when tree-shaking. Using Barrel files might also increase your bundle size!
Here are some interesting discussions no BlueSky regarding these issues:

Different bundle sizes
Build time or build size?


Do you call some functionality conditionally based on environment.production flag, where you don't want it to be bundled in production but only in development? I discovered that I used if(!environment.production) { devFunction() } in main.ts, where Angular 15 builder did not bundle devFunction() for production, but Angular 17 did. I had to move devFunction() call from main.ts to evironment.ts. In this case Angular uses fileReplacement and for production it takes environment.production.ts instead, so devFunction() is not included at all.

Hey @jurev, interesting point. I'm going to check that out and get back to you asap.

I had also observed this bundle increase after new esbuild, did you find the root cause

Haven't had time to check @jurev suggestion. I'll get back with feedback this week

@jurev I check my project and where's no conditional environment functionality in the code. I recently upgraded the project to Angular 18 and added some extra dependencies since I posted this question, and what I noticed is that the estimated transfer size between the two build systems decreased a little. But there's still a noticeable difference between the two raw bundle sizes.

@Ricky, I suggest you analyze your compiled bundles using these techniques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567781/angular-cli-output-how-to-analyze-bundle-files. It's best you analyze main.js on both Angular 15 and 18 builds, so you will be able to identify which bundled dependencies have different sizes in both builds. That's how I was able to identify my issue. Maybe some 3rd party lib is causing your problem beause it might be somehow incompatible with Vite compiler optimizations. Please post your findings.

Thanks @jurev! Will check it out and then get back with feedback
