# Angular 9 - lodash is imported in prod bundle even after using with lodash-es

Tags: angular, webpack, lodash

This is my first question here. I hope I'll be clear!
I am developing an Angular app, version 9.1.13.

After some analysis of my current prod bundle using `webpack-bundle-analyzer`, I discovered that lodash was completly loaded into the bundle. So I followed the explanations given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991178/correct-way-of-importing-and-using-lodash-in-angular) to evict lodash and use lodash-es instead.

I am able to see lodash-es in the prod bundle now BUT lodash is still there too. Here is the result:
[new-bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjbbE.png)

I looked for some other dependencies using lodash with `npm list --prod lodash`: I found one (@angular/localize) and it should not be responsible for this according to this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36813)

```
└─┬ @angular/localize@9.1.13
  └─┬ @babel/core@7.8.3
    ├─┬ @babel/traverse@7.12.13
    │ └── lodash@4.17.20  deduped
    ├─┬ @babel/types@7.12.13
    │ └── lodash@4.17.20  deduped
    └── lodash@4.17.20
```

I don't have any ideas about how to solve this. Have you ever faced this issue?

P.S.: below is my build configuration

```
        "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/co-investir-frontend/browser",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": true,
        "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/sitemap.xml",
          "src/robots.txt"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "index": {
            "input": "src/index.prod.html",
            "output": "index.html"
          },
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "5mb",
              "maximumError": "10mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "20kb",
              "maximumError": "30kb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually discovered that an external library mentioned lodash in its peer dependencies which caused `npm list --prod lodash` not to return its name.

The only way I could find this was to use `ngx-build-plus` and write a small extra webpack config used on top of the one used by Angular CLI.

```
// extra-webpack.config.yts
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    externals: {
        moment: 'moment'
    }
};
```

Serving the application did show errors coming from this library asking for `lodash`!

The solution was then to ask the owner of the library to use `lodash-es` instead of `lodash` which he did.

Now everything is working and `lodash` is no more in the bundle!