# Export specific module from lodash-es/lodash.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack-2

I have a question regarding importing, for example, join from lodash.
As stated by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251059/4408782) answerer, the way to go would be the following:

```
import join from 'lodash-es/join'
```

(File size of my dist/bundle.js after `webpack --optimize-minimize`: 1K)

But I'd like to import **only the join function** from [lodash-es/lodash.js](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/b1ff59b3ea86aefb67676e4e3f5ff636c23fd6c7/lodash.js).
However, this does not seem to be possible.

[lodash-es/lodash.js](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/b1ff59b3ea86aefb67676e4e3f5ff636c23fd6c7/lodash.js) uses this to export the library:

```
export { default as add } from './add.js';
export { default as after } from './after.js';
export { default as ary } from './ary.js';
export { default as assign } from './assign.js';
```

I've already tried:

```
import join from 'lodash-es'
```

(File size: 133K)

```
import { join } from 'lodash-es'
```

(File size : 133K)

```
import { join } from 'lodash-es/lodash.js'
```

(File size : 133K)

Apparently none of these work since the entire lib is assigned to `join`.

So how do I import **only** `lodash/join` from the [lodash.js](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/b1ff59b3ea86aefb67676e4e3f5ff636c23fd6c7/lodash.js)-file **without** targeting the specific file?

I am using webpack 2.5.1 and lodash-es 4.17.4

Comment: Doesn't `import { join } from 'lodash-es';` with `new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ minimize: true });` work?

Comment: I added this in the `module.exports.plugins` array in my webpack.config.js but `import { join } from 'lodash-es;'` still assigns the entire library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 variable import name in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168433/es6-variable-import-name-in-node-js)

Comment: @Paul Sweatte no, I'm not trying to pass a variable to `import`