# Reducing Lodash imports / bundle sizes via module

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lodash, tree-shaking

So I'm going through trying to reduce bundle sizes, starting with one of the common culprits -- Lodash, kind of following this [article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark) as I go because obviously this is not ideal;

[image]

So I go in and start trying to do the basic task of doing the module imports of just what's actually getting used like going from `import * as _ from 'lodash'` to `import each from 'lodash/each'`

Except doing that I get as example `.../node_modules/@types/lodash/each"' has no default export.` Which is confusing, because I see the export in there, I have my @types for it in there showing everything should be fine, but I'm obviously missing some inane detail. Do I have to use `lodash-es` since my module is `es2015`? Am I understanding that's why `esModuleInterop` in the `tsconfig` set to true will puke at me? Guess I'm just looking for whatever little detail I'm apparently missing.

Angular 6/CLI

Target: es5

Module: es2015

Comment: try lodash-es https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es, I think it does tree-shaking better

Comment: I still don't understand why some drive-by downvoter wouldn't even give an explanation for their stance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the tree-shakeable import:

```
import each from 'lodash-es/each';
```

As the `npm package` states, it really is just the ES6 module export of the original package:

```
The Lodash library exported as ES modules.

Generated using lodash-cli:

$ lodash modularize exports=es -o ./
See the package source for more details.
```

Further explanation can be found here: [Correct way to import lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35250500/correct-way-to-import-lodash/50656694#50656694)

Comment: So would you use lodash-es in lieu of lodash or together? Makes sense that es is just lodash as es mods.

Comment: lodash is a dependency of lodash-es. I think the latter just adds proper support for types and tree shaking. Remove lodash and install lodash-es, both should appear in node_modules

Comment: We'll call it good. Almost have it cut in half with lodash-es, now if I could figure out how to mod a chained method like for example `_(<param>).last().key;` since it won't let me do like `import * as _ from 'lodash-es'` as a one-for-one import replacement....

Comment: OH AND JUST TO CLARIFY FOR FUTURE READERS*** `import { each, find } from 'lodash-es';` for example will include the whole library, you need to do separate `import each from 'lodash-es/each';` `import find from 'lodash-es/find';` for example if you want the tree-shaking benefit...

Comment: Is this a drop-in replacement for `lodash` in an existing project, or will it require updating the code?

Comment: @HashimAziz it's lodash as es6 modules, so the declarations would remain the same but you'd need to update the imports like stated above accordingly.