# JS React import difference bundle size

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's the difference these imports in terms of React application bundle size?

```
import _ from 'lodash' // then use _.get
import { get } from 'lodash'
import get from 'lodash/get'
```

Comment: I think this would depend greatly on your specific app structure, chosen bundler, and configuration settings. What is stopping you from experimenting and finding out for yourself - run a build with each of the three possibilities and compare the bundle sizes.

Comment: Found correct answer I was looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35250500/correct-way-to-import-lodash

Answer (score 0):

Found correct answer I was looking for here

```
import concat from 'lodash/concat';
import orderBy from 'lodash/orderBy';
import filter from 'lodash/filter';
```

it only loads the needed modules (results in smaller bundler size)

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark